# Insulting email from another graduate student

Tags: ethics, academic-life

I'm first year international graduate student in US and recently I have received an insulting email (for example including "be thankful and keep your mouth shut") from a domestic student who is my teammate in a class project. The email was a follow up to my debate with another teammate, however there wasn't any context for anything like that (I consider all of university email as public records and I'm careful about what I write), and initial conflict was going to be resolved with few email exchange. When I brought up the issue to the class professor, he (the student) claimed that he was angry because of my position in the debate and he was defending the other team member, but overall he (the student) defended his email. The professor tried to calm us down and avoid escalating the conflict.

I have experienced similar but milder situation with other domestic students and in one case a young professor as well. The general hostility pattern is that, they expect me to keep my mouth shut and be second class citizen. I have heard from other international students that our small city/university is not a good place regarding this issue. My question is, can I do anything about it?

Comment: Trying to listen to the other student and find out what upsets them about the exchange can defuse a situation.  It may be good to take a conciliatory approach such as saying "I'm sorry I seem to have offended you; can we talk about this more so I understand what this issue means to you?" might be productive.  Hard to say without knowing the details though.

Comment: @dan1111 I generally agree with you, but when someone makes a direct and insulting attack it is difficult to take a conciliatory approach.

Comment: Voting to close, nobody can help you here without knowing the specifics. Plus any answer that will try to generalize to all "American" students is going to be inherently useless.

Comment: @CapeCode I replaced American with domestic. What specifics you expect?

Comment: Well you got into a fight with other people, the only information you give us is that it was by email and that the other people are American. This information is completely irrelevant. But *if* you were giving the specifics, it would be off topic because it would strongly depend on aspects only you and the other people involved would know. Not to mention the whole thread would be useless to anyone else than you. Don't get me wrong, I hope that you're issue will be fixed, I just don't think it's a fit for this site.

Comment: @CapeCode No, I wasn't fighting, it was a discussion/debate about a team work issue with another international student, but because the domestic student's view was totally different from mine, he jumped in with an insulting email, as if he has the right to final say and also to insult me.

Comment: "A dispute" then. Same comment apply.

Comment: @CapeCode yes, but my question is not about the dispute itself, it is about his insulting email, when no one else was using that language.

Comment: Are you sure that this person is indeed trying to insult you? Can it be just a form of expression? I would first check with an American that this is not some kind of misunderstanding due to cultural differences.

Comment: +1. Key quotes that are ignored in the discussion here are "...he was defending the other team member", and to be "thankful" (for what?). There is more to this story, and its omission makes me uncomfortable. 
It's unfortunate to jump to full-blown PC mode and criticize this reasonable answer just because. Thanks for saying what I find a reasonable person would read into the question w/o thought control.

Comment: @Bitwise: As an American I can confirm that the phrasing used is rude.

Comment: It seems like you've already decided that the problem is international students being treated badly by domestic students and staff at your school. In that case, the solution is move to another school. If you want a useful answer, you should describe the facts of the matter and not jump to conclusions like "I bet it's because I'm international!"

Comment: I would like to add that for conduct with private citizens (especially in private institutions, government funding or not) it's generally not acceptable to say whatever you want to someone else. As an American, I can confidently say that people misinterpret freedom of speech, as it's really intended for freedom *from* the government, not for interactions with other private citizens. Perhaps the problem here is bidirectional? As in you've both misinterpreted what's acceptable to say to other people.

Comment: I wonder if this question would be off-topic, if it would be about gender or sex discrimination, not racial/national one. While it is true that the question is very general or that OP may misjudged the situation, however it is still a valid question about what is the proper procedure to resolve race/national based hostility (either true or perceived) in American universities.

Comment: @Bitwise Yes, that was overall theme of his email, I showed the entire email thread to some of my friends and they had same idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to say that some of your comments on here are coming across as rather defensive and argumentative.

Sometimes trying to place blame, or argue about who was in the wrong, is just counter productive - you can't change what has already happened. It sounds clichéd, but sometimes the best way to deal with a situation like this is to be the bigger person, apologise for any offence and walk away. Hold you're head high that you're not stooping to the level of sending insulting emails.

But do consider @Alexandros' advice. Consider the situation, and consider other ways that you could perhaps have de-escalated it earlier. This *isn't* victim blaming, just self-improvement. We can all improve how we behave. Perhaps there is nothing that you could have done, and that's fine, but consider it.

In terms of your general situation, I don't think that anyone here can answer that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I agree with you, in many cases it is easier to solve an issue by not arguing. But a pattern of hostility from domestic students here still exists, they somehow believe they have the right to be hostile and they can be prude of it.

Comment: @Pahil, honestly, don't lower yourself to their level. Beat them by conducting yourself well and professionally. Hold your head high in the knowledge that you're the better person. If they want to be hostile, let them. Try not to react to it. I know it's hard, and I wish you all the best - I hope that things get better for you.

Comment: You are right, already I regret about every single time that I have reacted and I'm glad about every time that I didn't. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 22):

I cannot give you advise on what to do in this situation as it depends strongly on the context, and you cannot give that information on an open forum like this.

However, I can make one comment: in general I would never try to solve such a conflict through email. Email is great, but when you sense that a conflict might start you immediately need to stop using email and try to speak with the person directly. Small misunderstandings that are easily resolved in face to face communication tend to get blown out of proportion very quickly in an email conversation.

Comment: s/resolved/suppressed by someone being embarrassed into giving up his or her position/ and then I would say +1. It's reasonable advice.

Answer (score 9):

> Recently I have received an insulting email (for example including "be
> thankful and keep your mouth shut") from an ... American student who
> is my teammate
>
> The email was a follow up to my debate with another teammate...
>
> I have experienced similar but milder situation with other American
> students...
>
> ...and in one case a young American professor

Do you notice the pattern here? It seems as though you a have a problem with many people you meet in a work environment (academia) that is generally tolerant of other cultures, international students and people with different backgrounds. Have you even considered the possibility that instead of blaming everyone else, that the only common element of all those cases is you? If not, you should probably start considering the possibility that you are also doing something wrong. Then try to fix it ASAP.

On the other hand, there are always obnoxious people in every work environment out there, so in those cases try to be professional and limit your interactions with them at a stricty professional level. Not all people can get along and be friends. Limiting unnecessary interactions with people you cannot get along can help you avoid further "debates" in the future.

Comment: -1 This is really obnoxious victim-blaming.  There certainly are a non-trivial number of jerks amongst American students (as one might expect in any student population).

Comment: I don't think that this is *obnoxious victim-blaming* at all. In a conflict situation, it is always a good idea to reflect on ones own actions and consider how the situation could have been dealt with differently to avoid the conflict happening in the first place. You are only in control of how *you* deal with a situation, not the other person. Even if the other person is just a jerk, there are always ways better and worse to deal with that. Unfortunately as an international student, the OP has certain cultural differences to deal with. It can take some time to adjust.

Comment: With that said, there is rarely a situation where an email along the lines of *be thankful and keep your mouth shut* should be considered acceptable, but we just don't have the context leading up to that point.

Comment: @Pahil I do not know you or the other students. In my workspace, I try not to be confrontational and even though you there are things that you cannot let slide, if I do not really like someone I minimize contact outside what is required by professional courtesy. I avoid escalating personal confrontation to supervisors because that makes me also look bad. But I have not really faced any serious bullying (that I could not handle myself) in the workplace, so your case might be different.

Comment: @zelanix There was not really any context allowing that language, especially that I know every thing I send through university email is somehow a public record.

Comment: @Alexandros Actually the first time that I faced a similar situation I peacefully walked away and didn't talked about it, but they went to our professor and thrown me under the bus, which was really supersizing for me.

Comment: If *"be thankful and keep your mouth shut"* is a verbatim quote, then in the absence of some significantly extenuating context, the person who wrote that appears to be at fault.

Comment: @jakebeal I don't think this is victim blaming. Considering if one is doing something to trigger this behaviour is a good idea; where the answer may very well be "no, they are all jerks".

Comment: +1. Key quotes that are ignored in the discussion here are "...he was defending the other team member", and to be "thankful" (for what?). There is more to this story, and its omission makes me uncomfortable. 
It's unfortunate to jump to full-blown PC mode and criticize this reasonable answer just because. Thanks for saying what I find a reasonable person would read into the question w/o thought control.

Comment: @Moriarty Yes, without context, it's very hard to tell what's meant.  At the same time, that exact phrase could easily be used in a much less rude manner.  E.g., if someone says, "yes, you have a good point, but in cases like this, sometimes all you can do is be thankful and keep your mouth shut" wouldn't really be offensive at all.  I don't think there's really enough context here.

Answer (score 1):

If you've made a complaint and aren't happy with the resolution then you can escalate. That's not to say you *should*, though, you should only do that if you're unhappy with the resolution *and* you think the professor handled the incident so badly that a different handling is needed. It's not unusual for *nobody* to be happy with the outcome of an incident like this.

The other student acknowledged he acted in anger. Maybe he'll reflect more carefully about ever doing it again, in which case you have a modestly positive result. But what are you hoping for, an apology? A formal warning to the student? Tarring and feathering? A complete end to American exceptionalism in any form from any person? ;-)

Depending what you want affects what options are available to do something about it. But if what you want is for the other student's wrongness to be formally acknowledged and warned/punished, then really you need to start by going to someone familiar with your own institution's disciplinary system and asking what they would *expect* the outcome of such a case to be.

There isn't anything in the fragment you quote to tie this aggression against you (that you are somehow ungrateful and should not speak) to the fact you're not American. If the context does tie it in (for example if the intention is in context clearly, "you should be grateful to have been allowed into the country, and immigrants should not have the right to speak in this University"), then you might have an example in which the University authorities would take an interest. They take foreign students, they probably therefore don't want them kept quiet. But the professor who's already seen the case thinks it's not that bad, so personally I wouldn't bet on it. It's "just" speech, so I expect has to meet a fairly high bar to be censured, albeit that such principles have been known in some places to be applied patchily and unfairly.

If there's a wide pattern of hostility from certain of the domestic students, against foreign students, then you aren't going to establish it from a single incident. The only productive option really is for you, other people who've experienced it, and preferably allies who don't experience it but would like it to stop, to make a *sustained* attempt to raise awareness that it's going on and to convince people that it's a bad thing. I'm not an experienced civil rights activist and I don't want to advise you how to conduct that campaign. It needn't necessarily be protests and banners and formal complaints. I do want to point out that as long as the narrative is, "these isolated incidents do not reflect the values of this institution" then they will continue. Only by turning the narrative into "the values of this institution are not yet adequate to address these continual incidents and should change" does anything happen.

Comment: I don't seek punishment but I'm just getting tired of repeating pattern of hostility, they generally expect me to keep my mouth shut and be a second class citizen. There were not anything racial directly in email, I just said I have seen this behavior from only a specific type of people. Thanks for your comments anyway.

Comment: @Pahil: yes, I imagine it's really tough, but that realistically the situation might be, "does not reflect the values of this institution but also not something this institution is interested in doing anything about". If there's no recourse and you must suffer, then suffer in company. It seems like the problem is recognised by the other international students you mention. But even jerks and even racists get to go to University somewhere, so recognising it won't end it.